# Is "Character" a keyword or reserved method in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I keep getting a compilation error with my class "Character" but if I put it in a module it works fine... even if I leave it as an empty class with nothing in there.

When I say class it is not a "real" class as im just looking at porting some old Javascript to Typescript but it looks like:

```
function Character() {
 // Blows up
}
```

but...

```
Module Something
{
    function Character() {
        // Works
    }
}
```

I am mainly putting this up incase someone else has this almost unsolvable issue like me (as I was just commenting out everything until the error stopped).

== EDIT ==

The error I get when I dont put it in a module is:

```
tsc.js(14053, 13) Microsoft JScript runtime error: please implement in derived classFailed to compile files: <a couple of *.ts files>
```

Comment: That should be `module Something` (module is case-sensitive) - right? Maybe try posting more code - the problem is not the name of the function.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not my code to post, so I will just have to put this down to there being something conflicting within the code. One other thing to mention is that the offending code in reality is also referencing Knockout.d.ts, Knockout.Mapping.d.ts, Knockout.Validation.d.ts and Jquery.d.ts.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm going to (with all apologies) Vote to Close then, as I don't think this can be answered in its present format.

Comment: That's fine, I would delete the question but on the off chance this is one of those really niche errors someone else gets and realises its a naming conflict somewhere I would rather keep it available. Thanks for taking the time to help me attempt to diagnose though, I have put a vote in too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function named `Character` works just fine in the [Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=function%20Character%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log%2842%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0ACharacter%28%29%3B).

Comment: Doesnt work for me, using the tsc.exe which comes with the visual studio plugin, although invoked from the command line. I am compiling other classes but there are only 3 and none of them have a function named Character. I have added the error I receive when trying to compile it.

Comment: Do you get the same problem using the Node.js TypeScript compiler?

Comment: Don't have or use nodeJS so couldn't tell you, sorry